Relationship between the parts of a complex number with its conjugate
Edit (2024-07-13): $\mathrm{arg}(z) = \frac{1}{i}\ln\sqrt{\frac{z}{\bar z}}$ is true only for $z>0$, so it is irrelevant. It is not the case for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. So, the relationship asked is valid only for the functions of the real part and absolute value.
Edit (2024-07-14): Substitution of previous definitions for the imaginary part and the argument of a complex number $z$ to another that is valid and preserves the relationship asked in the question. Also, formatting.

The parts of a complex number $z$ can be represented alongside its conjugate $\bar z$ as variables with the real part as $\mathrm{Re}(z) = \frac{z+\bar z}{2}$, imaginary part as $\mathrm{Im}(z) = \frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$, absolute value as $\mathrm{abs}(z) = \sqrt{z \bar z}$, and argument as $\mathrm{arg}(z) = \frac{1}{i}\ln\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{z\bar z}}\right)$ for $z\neq 0$.
But there is a relationship between the real part and the absolute value, the same way that there is a relationship between the imaginary part and the argument of the complex number z. Rewriting to make some operations explicit:
$$ \mathrm{Re}(z) = \left(z+ \bar z \right)2^{-1} $$
$$ \mathrm{abs}(z) = \left(z\cdot \bar z \right)^{ 2^{-1} } $$
$$ \mathrm{Im}(z) = (z +(z +\bar{z}){2^{-1}}({-1}))i^{-1} $$
$$\mathrm{arg}(z) = \ln(z \cdot(z \cdot\bar{z})^{{2^{-1}}({-1})})i^{-1} $$
From the real part to the absolute value, addition becomes multiplication and multiplication by $2^{-1}$ becomes exponentiation by $2^{-1}$. From the imaginary part to the argument, again, addition becomes multiplication, and multiplications by $(-1)$ and $2^{-1}$ become exponentiations (not considering the natural logarithm).
Something similar happens when we represent complex numbers in rectangular and polar form, if a unique symbol for the complex constant $e^i$ is used, which will be represented as $\varrho$:
$$z = a+ ib = r\cdot\varrho^{\theta}.$$
Is there a connection that explains this?

This requires some algebraic background, but yes. In general, if $L/K$ is a finite field extension, there are two special functions from $L$ to $K$ called the field trace $\text{tr}_{L/K}$ and the field norm $N_{L/K}$. They can be defined in several equivalent ways, but the one relevant here is that if $L/K$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$, then
$$\text{tr}_{L/K}(a) = \sum_{g \in G} ga$$
$$N_{L/K}(a) = \prod_{g \in G} ga;$$
in other words, the trace and norm are the sum and the product of the elements $ga, g \in G$, which are called the conjugates of $a$ and correspond to the roots of its minimal polynomial (with some multiplicities). Loosely speaking, the trace and the norm are the two simplest ways to "average" an element of $L$ to get an element of $K$. From their definitions you can see that the trace is additive while the norm is multiplicative, which is useful in proofs.
Now $\mathbb{C}$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb{R}$, even a Galois extension with Galois group cyclic of order $2$ generated by complex conjugation $z \mapsto \bar{z}$. So the use of the term "conjugate" above generalizes this familiar case. It follows that the field trace and the field norm in this case are
$$\text{tr}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(z) = z + \bar{z} = 2a$$
$$N_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(z) = z \bar{z} = a^2 + b^2.$$
The division by $2$ and the square root are not essential and in the general theory aren't always possible so should be avoided. They amount to the "averaging" I mentioned; they're just designed so that if $z$ is a (non-negative) real then the output is $z$ again, but this isn't that important. From here, writing the imaginary part in terms of $z - \bar{z}$ and the argument in terms of $\frac{z}{\bar{z}}$ is an instance of a simple general pattern where $(a, b)$ can be recovered from $(a + b, a - b)$ and vice versa.

Very interesting! Is this "average" related to arithmetic mean and geometric mean? That's why the division by 2 and square root? That's how I'm thinking about these functions and relationships. The final part still confuses me. How does $z-\bar z$ and $\frac{z}{\bar z}$, which also can be written as $\bar z -z$, if $\mathrm{Im}(z)=\left( \left(\bar z + z(-1) \right) 2^{-1} \right) i$, and $\frac{\bar z}{z}$, if $\mathrm{arg}(z) = \ln\left( ( ( \bar z\cdot{z}^{(-1)} )^{2^{-1}} )^{i} \right)$, how they relate with this general pattern which recover $(a,b)$ from $(a+b,a-b)$ and vice versa?

@g. bressan: you can say it the following way. Both constructions $z + \bar{z}$ and $z \bar{z}$ have the effect of producing a real number for abstract reasons, since they are both fixed by complex conjugation: the complex conjugates are $\bar{z} + z$ and $\bar{z} z$ which are of course the same. So you can think of these as two different ways of isolating the "real part" of $z$. Now to recover $z$ itself you also need some kind of "imaginary part" of $z$. The effect of the minus sign in $z - \bar{z}$ and the division in $\frac{z}{\bar{z}}$ is that they guarantee a specific...

...kind of behavior with respect to complex conjugation, namely, the complex conjugate of $z - \bar{z}$ is its own negative, while the complex conjugate of $\frac{z}{\bar{z}}$ is its own inverse. So we get a purely imaginary number resp. an element of the unit circle (which is the exponent of a purely imaginary number). I don't know if this is entirely satisfying but the two are closely analogous, and furthermore one is sent to the other by the complex exponential.
